# New external drive already slow to mount and to read/write

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, mount, benchmarking

I just bought a 5TB Seagate STJL5000400 external USB hard drive.

It takes at least 20 seconds to mount before being available to browse folders in the file manager and writing / reading is so slow.

I have since 2 years another 3TB external hard drive (Seagate Maxtor STSHX-D301TDBM) almost full, which mounts in 3 seconds and I access the data very quickly.

Both have "fuse" as file system.

I have copied almost all of the content from the Maxtor to the new one (in days...).

The exact same folder containing 1000 files for a total of 1GB takes 1 second to show the content on the Maxtor, while over 10 seconds on the new one.
I am using the same desktop PC, with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, connecting them both on usb 2.0 (My PC does not have USB 3.0 ports) and iI'm using the original USB cables that came with the external drive.

Why are mounting and reading so slow on the new hdd? I was expecting much better speed than the old one.

How do I know if the new one is faulty or damaged or not good enough with respect to the information provided by the seller?

**Edit**:

Maxtor:

[image]

Seagate Basic:

[image]

[image]

**`smartctl -a /dev/<disk>; smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>; sleep 121; smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`**:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              Basic
Revision:             0712
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        5.000.981.077.504 bytes [5,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Logical Unit id:      [...]
Serial number:        NABSCJN4
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sun Mar 27 23:13:39 2022 CEST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -       0                 - [-   -    -]
```

Comment: Are you using the USB3 cable it came with, and if not, what is the length of the cable being used _(cable length matters with USB3)_?

Comment: Why use USB2.0 when USB3 exists?

Comment: @JW0914 yes, I'm using the USB cable it came with and it's 30cm long.

Comment: @Gantendo because my PC does not have USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: @user2342558 If you have an available PCI or PCI Express expansion slot and 20$ you can add some USB3 ports.

Comment: @user2342558 I'm not familiar with the Fuse filesystem, but only a few things could be the likely cause: (1) Pull the S.M.A.R.T output & perform a short test: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>; smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>; sleep 121; smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` - please post the output of the last command; (2) Do a filesystem scan to ensure its not corrupted, and if not, wipe the disk and reformat; (3) If that doesn't resolve it, determine if it's the USB3 interface on the drive by removing the HDD from it's external casing and connecting it directly to the PC's SATA port. Or just exchange the drive

Comment: @JW0914 i posted some info and images. Thanks

Comment: @user2342558 If it's not an inconvenience, I'd simply return the drive and exchange it for another, as there's no way to determine if the drive is actually the issue since it doesn't support S.MA.R.T. _(Depending on personal preference and cost factors, you may want to consider a different model of external drive that supports S.M.A.R.T or buying the components separately [external casing and 2.5" drive], which allows you to use any 2.5" drive you want - the only reason I'm mentioning that is a lack of S.M.A.R.T support on a multi-TB drive prevents checking the health of the hardware itself)_